# Program will not load Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, boolean, logic, operators

I am trying to create a code that will determine your school grade by entering your university credits and will output the student name and grade. However I am getting an error I have never seen before. I am new to this and can't seem to debugg it. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>University Credits</title>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                        /* Input Name and Credits from user.
                         * Process the studnets number of university credits.
                         * Outputs the student's Name and School year.
                        */

                    function credits() {
                        //Get name and univesity credits from user.
                        var studentName = document.getElementById("nameBox").value;
                        var creditNumber = parseFloat(document.getElementById("creditBox").value);
                        /*Compute number of credits to determine school grade.

                        If the number of credits is     And the number of credits           Then the year in school is:
                        greater than or equal to:            is less than:  
                                    0                              30                           freshman
                                    30                             60                           sophomore
                                    60                             90                           junior
                                    90                             ∞                            senior
                        */
                        var credits;

                        if (creditNumber >= 0 || creditNumber < 30){
                        credits="freshman"
                        }else if (creditNumber >= 30 || creditNumber < 60){
                        credits="sophomore"
                        }else if (creditNumber >= 60  || creditNumber < 90){
                        credits="sophomore"
                        }else if (creditNumber >= 90 || creditNumber < number.MAX_VALUE){
                        credits="sophomore"
                        }
                        //Display nameand grade to user.
                        var nameCredit= studentName + creditNumber;
                        document.getElementById("nameGrade").innerHTML = nameCredit;
                     }
                </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>Enter you Name and University Credits to determinet your school grade.</h1>
                    Name: <input type= "text" id= "nameBox" size=3>
                    University Credits: <input type="text" id= "creditBox" size=3>
                    <button type="button" onlick="credits()">School Grade </button>                   
                </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 404 is a server returning resouce not found, drag your html page into chrome, it should run

Comment: It loads in chrome but it doesn't do anything. I then go into developer tools and that's where I see that error.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your developer tools?

Comment: Here is the link to the screenshot. Thanks!

http://oi66.tinypic.com/rvep8x.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The 404 error has nothing to do with your code. The error is because your browser is not finding a [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). Browsers look for `favicon.ico` in the root directory of your web server; it is the icon that appears on the browser tab for the page or by a bookmark, shortcut, etc. If you don't have a `favicon.ico` file on your server (in this case the one you are running on your local machine) you will get a 404 error for it. Not having one doesn't hurt anything, it just means browsers might complain when they don't find it.

It appears that your code is not attempting to run because of a typo. Instead of attaching an event handler to the [`click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) you are attaching it to the non-existent `lick` event:

```
<button type="button" onlick="credits()">School Grade</button>
```

Also the code you posted won't display any output, the DOM doesn't contain a `nameGrade` element to output to.